# Start Jetty application but "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate fragment name"

Tags: spring, gradle, jetty

Sorry if duplicated.

I am using gradle to build my .war file and start my application using Jetty. But I see this error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate fragment name: spring_web for jar:file:/private/var/folders/r7/z7yqbhx10wl9kyw738crggdd0zwztx/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-application-1.0.war-_pplication-1.0-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml and jar:file:/private/var/folders/r7/z7yqbhx10wl9kyw738crggdd0zwztx/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-cpplication-1.0.war-_pplication-1.0-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml
```

I already did some research on internet, but all are talking about jetty-maven-plugin and the solution is to add `"<allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>"` to webAppConfig. But in my application I don't have webAppConfig. Is this only for Maven? How to solve this if I am using Gradle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can put jetty.xml under WEB-INF

jetty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC
    "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
    "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="allowDuplicateFragmentNames">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

In your WEB-INF/web.xml, look for the  tag (should be at the top), and modify atributes to match these values:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="true"
..
>
```

Comment: This worked for me, after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626429/the-prefix-xsi-for-attribute-xsischemalocation-associated-with-an-element-t) follow up.