# The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "web-app" is not bound

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

Error Seen while starting tomcat:

> javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "web-app" is not bound.

I am trying to deploy my Java (Maven Based) projects onto my Tomcat 8 server and start it. After cleaning all the project and building the workspace; After removing all build path errors on each project. When I try to deploy the projects in tomcat and start it, i get below error:

```
    Apr 02, 2018 1:29:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [action] in web application [/bss] threw load() exception
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "web-app" is not bound.
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:402)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1140)
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue and which jar is exactly missing which will resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post your `web.xml`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably missing the declaration of the `xsi` namespace in your `web.xml` file. Add `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to the `web-app` element. Example:

```
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">
   <!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: I do have the above present in my web.xml file

Comment: @JasmiraRichelleFernandes Post your `web.xml`.